# Повторное использование части кода

Tags: java

Какие есть способы, методы для ссылки на повторное использование части кода, написанного ранее, во избежание повторений и увеличения размерности кода. По собственным поискам подобной информации узнал, что "goto", которым ранее пользовался в других языка, в "java", как такового, - нет. Может, есть другие варианты?

Comment: Чтобы избегать повторений, нужно использовать разбиение на классы/методы/функции, а не goto.

Comment: ни в коем случае не используй goto в java, используй классы/методы/функции, это самый легкий язык для погружения в ООП
(а если все же будешь использовать метки, то никому не говори об этом)

Answer (score 2):

В java есть аналог GOTO - это использование конструкции:

```
break метка;
```

Но данная конструкция нарушает структуру кода и не рекомендуется к использованию. В нормальном коде она не встречается. Для повторного использования кода в нормальном java коде придется пользоваться вещами посложнее: инкапсуляции, композиции, программирование на уровне интерфейсов, а не реализаций, слабая связность и куча всего остального. Как вы поняли, это тема очень обширная для одного ответа. Крайне рекомендую книгу "Head First Паттерны проектирования". Там очень хорошо описаны основные приемы, которые помогут вам с повторным использованием кода и многим другим
Но на начальных этапах, банально можно выносить код, который можно использовать несколько раз в отдельные методы. Это уже позволит сократить длину кода.

Answer (score 1):

Аналогом `goto` в Java с натяжкой можно назвать метки. Когда в программе несколько вложенных циклов, то операторы `break` и `continue` по умолчанию действуют на самый глубоко вложенный цикл. С использованием меток можно указать операторам конкретный цикл, на который они будут действовать, например, самый внешний:

```
outer:
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
            if (j == 500 || i == 500)
                break outer;
        }
    }
```

При использовании операторов `break`/`continue` они будут действовать, как уже было сказано, на самый ближайший к ним цикл.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
        if (j == 500 || i == 500)
            break;
    }
}
```

Метки в Java существуют только для операторов `break` и `continue`.

---

P.S. [Список ключевых слов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) включает в себя `goto`. Однако данный оператор помечен как - not used (не используется).